# Copying a jar file from Windows 7 to Unix gives java.util.zip.ZipException

Tags: java, windows, unix, jar, winscp

I am copying a jar file from Windows 7 to my application lib folder on Unix machine through WinScp. On starting my application, i am getting the below error. Is the jar file corrupted while copying it. What is the correct way to copy the jar ?

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:72)
```

Comment: Check the MD5 on both sides.  `md5sum foo.jar`  on Linux, [HashTab](http://implbits.com/products/hashtab/) on windows.

Comment: Out of curiosity, because practically every non-Windows device is Unix, which Unix are you running? (Solaris, OSX, GNU/Linux, BSD, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using WinSCP in binary mode?  It does have a text transfer mode which will cock up a jar file.

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/transfer_settings